# How to structure a modular MITM proxy with python

Tags: python

To explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

Sometimes I visit website1.com, here I can download Linux ISOs but it's a bit annoying because it has a lot of ads, some of which are launched via javascript when I click the download button.

Sometimes I visit spotify.com but I hate green, so I'd like to modify all the images and css to make them red.

Sometimes I visit my local digital newspaper paper.com but they always ask something something pay to keep reading, something something disable adblock, usually I just inspect element and remove the overlay and keep reading.

Well, I thought I could make a mitmproxy script that runs 24/7 that would do all these things for me.

My idea was to create a main script that loads all modules found in `proxy_modules/` like `website1.py`, `reddit.py` and `paper.py`.

Some time ago I made a web scrapper to download articles, I had multiple websites coded but in `proxy_modules/` (called `ArticleDownloader`) I had a `__init__.py`

```py
__all__ = [
    "Website1Downloader",
    "Website2Downloader",
    "Website3Downloader",
    "Website4Downloader",
    "Website5Downloader",
    "Website6Downloader",
    "Website7Downloader",
    "Website8Downloader",
    "Website9Downloader"
    ]

from .Website1Downloader import Website1Downloader
from .Website2Downloader import Website2Downloader
from .Website3Downloader import Website3Downloader
from .Website4Downloader import Website4Downloader
from .Website5Downloader import Website5Downloader
from .Website6Downloader import Website6Downloader
from .Website7Downloader import Website7Downloader
from .Website8Downloader import Website8Downloader
```

Then in the main file I would `from ArticleDownloader import WebsiteDownloader1 as ArticleDownloader` and the rest of the code was the same for all website, since all WebsiteDownloader# classes would have the same methods and return the same things.

The "problem" is that for every Website I have to modify `__init__.py` to add the new website and then the main script where I import it.

With my mitmproxy project, is there a way to just add the new module and have the main script pick up all the files in `proxy_modules/` and load them automatically.

If so perhaps this could help me for any future projects where I face the same "problem".

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be describing [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey). It has built up a fairly mature ecosystem over the last two decades.

Comment: Not really, I want to use mitmproxy and modify requests before they're received by the browser/after they've left the browser. Additionally my solution could go "between the router and many PCs" while Greasemonkey would need to be installed in multiple PCs.

Comment: I've been reading and what I need is mitmproxy to act as a transparent proxy (Most likely in a VM in my host machine) and then set the host machine with the VM's IP as gateway.

Comment: How _exactly_ are you going to modify encrypted SSL requests? While in theory you can do this, do you know enough to set up your own certificate authority?

Comment: Is there a reason [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057534/1493294) won’t work?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yeas, I know how to set up my own certificate authority. candied_orange I don´t see why that wouldn't work, seems exactly like what I need to autoload the plugins.

Comment: @candied_orange just to clarify, if the script is already running and I add a new plugin that new file wouldn't be picked up, would it? Must I restart the script or is there a way to stop and reload in code? (FYI I plan to run it like this https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/discussions/5255#discussioncomment-2665643) (Something like a periodic `from . import *` and check if any new file has been imported?)

Comment: @david polling for a new file is a thing. But is restarting when you add/change code really such a bad thing?

Comment: @candied_orange Not really, just wondering about the possibilities. Even if weird it could happen that just as I restart the script a request comes through and gets lost because the script is restarting.

Comment: This question is more suited for Stackoverflow and already has answers there.

Answer (score 0):

[Import Python modules dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483074/125562)

```py
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('my_package.my_module')
my_class = getattr(module, 'MyClass')
my_instance = my_class()
```

The time and location to load can be determined with a [filesystem watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/)